# Why is the initializer list allowing type narrowing in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, type-narrowing

I see two different results while playing with the {} initializer list and primitive types in C++.

I get away only with a warning ***narrowing conversion of d from double to int inside {}***

```
double d {3.0};
int integer {d};
```

But if I make it more explicit then, instead of a warning, I get an error ***narrowing conversion of '3.0e+0' from 'double' to 'int' inside {}***

```
int integer {3.0};
```

Shouldn't C++11 prevent any narrowing conversion in both cases if {} is used? Then why is it happening only in one case?

I am using the latest version of Eclipse for C/C++ with MingGW. Is there any chance that C++14 has come in the way unintentionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With gcc variants you need to specify `-Werror=narrowing` to make this into error instead of warning. clang and vc++ are more strict and issue an error by default.

Comment: That's a clue. OK. Bjarne says in his book that it is an error.

Comment: @softwarelover Well, compilers are not perfect. most of them has various non-conforming features.

Comment: @softwarelover: The standard does not have the concept of "warning" and "error". All that is required is that such code is "ill-formed" and issue a diagnostic (aka: a message). The compiler can still continue on and compile the code as it sees fit; whether it does so is entirely up to the compiler.

Comment: How to do the opposite: to make error into warning in clang?